# Recursive Merge Sort Function Giving Bad Output

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, merge, mergesort

I am trying to figure out why my merge sort function is not working. I believe the problem is within the merge() part of it. here is my code:

```
int mergeSort(int *data, int left, int right) {
    //divide
    if (left < right) {
        int q = floor((left + right) / 2);
        //conquer
        mergeSort(data, left, q);
        mergeSort(data, q + 1, right);
        //combine
        merge(data, left, q, right);
    }

    //print results for testing purposes
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << data[i] << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the merge() part of it. I believe the problem is within this part.

```
int merge(int *data, int left, int q, int right) {
    int *temp = data;
    int i = left, j = q + 1, z = left;
    int t1 = 0, t2 = 0;
    while (i <= q && j <= right) { //while both variables have not reached the end of their sub arrays
        if (temp[i] <= temp[j]) {
            data[z] = temp[i];
            i++;
        }
        else {
            data[z] = temp[j];
            j++;
        }
        z++;
    }
     //if subarrays are both sorted and in order, combine them
    if (i < q) {
        t1 = z, t2 = i;
        for (t1; t1 < right;) {
            data[t1] = temp[t2];
            t1++;
            t2++;
        }
    }

    else if (j < right) {
        int t1 = z; int t2 = j;
        for (t1; t1 <= right;) {
            data[t1] = temp[t2];
            t1++;
            t2++;
        }
    }
```

I think that my problem is coming from declaring `int *temp = data;` at the beginning of `merge()`. My thought is that I'm getting some kind of memory address conflict between these two arrays, but I'm not sure.

I have tried arranging the data in different order, and have found that when a data needs to be moved from index n to index n-i, each index between these two indices is replaced with the value of n. For example:

the passing in the array `{4, 13, 8, 12, 9 }` would return `{4, 8, 8, 9, 9}`

My other thought is that the i and j variables are not incrementing correctly. I have been over this code repeatedly and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: It's a lot of tedious work, but have you tried stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger? That usually helps (and is an integral and important skill to know as a programmer).

Comment: You mention two arrays, but there is only ever one array allocated. My guess would be that one of the loops is overwriting some elements with copies of another element.

Comment: chemoroti, you and @dncook have nailed part of it. Both temp and data are pointing to the same pool of memory. Pointer A = pointer B does not copy the pointed at data, just the address. If you did this with a std::vector<int>, rather than a raw array, the assignment would have worked. Recommend following the advice in the first comment. There is probably no more efficient way to debug.

Comment: merge sort is a good fit for linked lists. for arrays, try [pivot sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (first line of the `merge` function)

```
int *temp = data;
```

does ***NOT*** copy an array; it just creates another pointer pointing to the same memory. This causes your code to overwrite your data.

You probably need to do something like this:

```
int * temp = new int [right - left + 1];
memcpy (temp, data + left, (right - left + 1) * sizeof(int));
```

and don't forget to `delete[]` the memory for `temp` at the end of your function:

```
delete[] temp;
```

Note that you'll need to change your use of `z`; it should start from `0`, not from `left`.

(The following are optional performance improvements; you can ignore them.)
Allocating and freeing memory in each `merge` function is a bad idea. Specially since we exactly know how much total extra memory we need for merging: an array of exactly `n` integers.

For this reason, it's a better idea to pass in another array of the same size along with `data` to `mergeSort`, so it can be used as scratch memory (i.e. temp memory) for merging. Or if you are really clever, you can *ping-pong* between the actual and the scratch memory to minimize copying.

Comment: Recommend replacing the malloc and free with new and delete to stay ideologically correct with C++. Smart pointer's not a bad idea, either.

Comment: @user4581301: I didn't realize that his code was C++. It's a sad day for the C++ language when its only sign is the use of `cout`...

Comment: I'm hesitant to use any C++11 features (`auto`, `unique_ptr`, etc.) or even STL (`std::copy`) because the OP's code is so not C++! I'm not even sure if he has any idea what C++ looks like, and I'm not trying to create more trouble for him.

Comment: I hear that. I was waffling on the smart pointer because it's probably overkill for the job.

Comment: ping-ponging buffers, while sorting continuous memory... sounds quite tricky

Comment: @sp2danny - As mentioned by yzt, a one time allocation of the temp buffer would be better, so say this is done in the entry function called MergeSort(). To ping pong buffers, MergeSort() calls a function MergeSortAtoA() which calls MergeSortAtoT() twice, then merges the two runs in T (temp) to A (array). MergesortAtoT() calls MergeSortAtoA twice, then merges the two runs in A (array) to T (temp).

Comment: For a bottom up merge sort, after each pass, the pointer to A (array) and T (temp) are swapped. To end up with sorted data in A, determine the number of passes needed (the ceiling of log2(n), which is a simple loop), then if the number of passes is odd, for the first pass swap in place (in A) instead of merging.